# Configure fileName of log4js in RollingFileStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, log4js-node

I am using log4js to log in my node js application. I have configured logger to create a new file when the file size reaches certain max size. The logger creates a file with same filename and '.' and index number is appended to the file name where index number is incremented every time a new file is created.

For e.g., running file is having filename as: `20150730060112.log`
then next files created are as

```
20150730060112.log.1, 
20150730060112.log.2
20150730060112.log.3 and so on...
```

I want a next file to be created with current timestamp and not with '.1'.